# How to retrieve the deleted content of an uncommitted file?

Tags: git

Consider exists the following files

```
a.adoc
b.adoc
c.adoc
e.adoc
```

Not sure what happened but `AsciidocFX` 1.8.6 **deleted the content** of these edited files, and is not possible do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>. So the current files are blank and **even worst they were saved!**, but not committed yet.

Is there a way through git to show the editions that were not committed? If is executed the `git status` command appears

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified: a.adoc  
    modified: b.adoc
    modified: c.adoc
    modified: d.adoc
    modified: e.adoc
```

With the `git diff a.adoc` command I can see everything deleted but based and comparing according with the latest commit for that file. BTW, the current point of the blank content to the latest previous commit of these files is big.

What I need it is show the content of the editions that were edited and saved by me but not committed through Git. Same approach as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> does. Is possible do something to fix this situation?

**Situation**

```
(1) Original latest files and committed
(2) Same files edited and saved but not committed and now deleted
(3) Files now in blank
```

How retrieve the deleted data of (2)?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do exactly. Do you want to restore the content from a commit (simple) or do you want to restore content that was never committed nor added (impossible)?

Comment: @RomainValeri But _"BTW, the current point of the blank content to the latest previous commit of these files is big"_ that is my worst scenario - restart to write again the lost edited content that was not committed ...

Comment: @ManuelJordan No, your worst scenario is — impossible to restore old content and no backup.

Comment: We're still unsure about what's "uncommited" here. Is it the files? (then you're out of luck) Or their deletion? (then their recovery is completely trivial)

Comment: Pls see the "Situation" section added

Comment: you can restore the state of a file from the last commit (HEAD) using `hit checkout yourfile.adoc`.

Comment: If you would like to get them back to what they were, you can use the index with `git restore -- some-file` or if you want it from `HEAD` (or any other commit) you can do `git restore --worktree --source HEAD-or-commit-id-or-branch -- some-file`

Comment: If the files were modified from the last commit, and you did _not_ at least add them to index before they were cleared, then git **can't** help you. If they had been added at some point, then those added objects will still be in the DB as dangling objects if you later changed what is in the index for those files.... if you added them and you did not touch what is in the index for them then you can use `git restore` to get them back, as I described.

Comment: About _add them to index before they were cleared_ with what command is accomplished that? It seems is not `git commit`... is the `git add` command? - _If they had been added at some point, then those added objects will still be in the DB as dangling objects if you later changed what is in the index for those files...._ it seems it is what I need ... if `git add` is the key to solve this ... sadly I didn't execute that command

Comment: @ManuelJordan Yes, it is the `git add` command. If you stage your changes, but don't commit them, it's a little tedious but usually possible to find and get your changes back. If you didn't stage them though, then Git doesn't even know about your changes yet, so unfortunately Git can't help you. The fact that the files were saved outside of Git, means possibly something outside of Git can help you. Maybe an automatic backup on your file system, or some editor that still has a copy? I think the painful lesson here might be to commit early and often. :(

Comment: Yes, due this I am not going to use that editor anymore, only to export purposes and perhaps for preview - now I changed to `Visual Studio Code` ... a bad way to start this week :(